# Adding custom content to sidebar in admin section's node edit page

Tags: nodes, forms, users

I want to add a custom image to the sidebar of the edit node page in the admin section.

[image: What I need]

Is there a hook that can allow me to do this?

Edie: I should point out the the image I want to show is dynamic and will be different for each page - determined by a conditional statement which will need to have access to the data of the node I am editing.

Comment: Just throwing it out there just in case.... Does that admin theme have a sidebar region? You could add a block?

Comment: I'm using a custom admin theme developed by a third party so would rather not mess with the code in that - would like to keep the code contained within my module. Thanks.

Comment: Yes thats fine, but go to structure > Blocks > Add new block. In the region settings area, use the select box underneath your admin themes name, and see if there is a sidebar region. It might be that you can simply add a block to the sidebar, without changing any code.

Comment: Thanks Collins, I have sidebar one and sidebar two however when I add a block to either of these it does no show in the node edit page. I can get the block to show on the dashboard but that;s about it. 

I should also mention that the image will be dynamic - pulled in with conditional statements - don't know if that's possible with this method....

Comment: If you can get it to appear in a block, then you can use views, or override the block in a template and use php to use the nid.
Can you get the image to appear in a block underneath the content instead? As wont the area you have selected move up and down when the vertical tabs are clicked?